Playing an audio file on server from Django
I have a Raspberry Pi that I have hooked up to a door chime sensor, so it plays different sounds as people enter the building. Right now, I just made a short script to play those sounds from whatever is in a directory, and it works fine.
I decided that it might be easier to upload sounds and organize their play order, if I setup a web server, and since I tend to use Django for all web servers, I thought I could get it to work. I know it's a pretty big hammer for such a small nail, but I use it regularly, so it's easy for me to use.
This code, when I put it in the Django InteractiveConsole, plays just fine.  When I try to call it from a PUT request in a view, it won't play the sound, but it also doesn't throw any errors. This is the case both on my computer and the Raspberry Pi.
>>> import vlc
>>> media_player = vlc.MediaPlayer()
>>> media = vlc.Media("/home/pi/chime/media/clips/clip1.mp3")
>>> media_player.set_media(media)
>>> media_player.play()

Is there something that would prevent these kinds of calls from running in a django view?  Is there a way to work around it?
EDIT: Django code example
class ClipsList(View):
    template_name = "clips/clip_list.html"

    # Ensure we have a CSRF cooke set
    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def get(self, request):
        ctx = {
            'object_list': Clip.objects.all().order_by('order'),
        }
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, context=ctx)

    # Process POST AJAX Request
    def post(self, request):
        if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
            try:
                # Parse the JSON payload
                data = json.loads(request.body)[0]
                # Loop over our list order. The id equals the question id. Update the order and save
                for idx, row in enumerate(data):
                    pq = Clip.objects.get(pk=row['id'])
                    pq.order = idx + 1
                    pq.save()

            except KeyError:
                HttpResponse(status="500", content="Malformed Data!")

            return JsonResponse({"success": True}, status=200)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"success": False}, status=400)

    def put(self, request, pk):
        if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
            try:
                data = json.loads(request.body)
                clip = Clip.objects.get(pk=pk)
                media_player = vlc.MediaPlayer()
                media = vlc.Media(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, str(clip.file)))
                media_player.set_media(media)
                media_player.play()
                sleep(3)
                media_player.stop()

            except KeyError:
                HttpResponse(status="500", content="Malformed Data!")
            return JsonResponse({"success": True}, status=200)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"success": False}, status=400)


Are you sure the code actually gets executed after the PUT request? Have you tried logging something to a file instead, to test this? Lack of an error message is not evidence that what you expected to happen happened.

I use Pycharm, and ran it in debug mode with a stop point, and it executes every command.  Or at least goes through the motions.  I see nothing that would suggest it's not working, other than I get no sound.

You should probably share a code example that provide an example of how it would be part of your Django application, so that people can try and replicate your issue. Given that you're running it in PyCharm, it would be running in your normal user context, so I don't see why it wouldn't play (although it might not in a production environment, depending on who or what runs Django).

I added the views for that page.  It doesn't work in PyCharm or on the Raspberry Pi, running through an Apache server.

Have you tried replacing the code in the try block with the literal code you shared that works from the interactive prompt? I.e. using a direct path, and none of the extra work you do with Clip etc.? Does that also not play a sound?

Well, that got me to the problem.  I used settings.BASE_DIR instead of settings.MEDIA_ROOT.  It still seems like it should have thrown an error in the console when it couldn't find a file.  If you want to write that up as an answer, I'll give you the credit.

You did all the work, I'm glad the issue got resolved - you should accept your own answer, if you feel it fully answers your question, so that your question appears as answered and is more likely to help others.

Based on some questions I was asked, I realized that I had used BASE_DIR instead of MEDIA_ROOT for the directory of the clips.  This fixed the problem on the development computer, but when served with Apache, it still wouldn't work until I added the www-data user to the audio, pulse, and pulse-access groups.
